Get the first match to a second table?
I am trying to return only one ship to zip line for each row but the query returns all unique lines.
select
  d.V4ORD as Order_Number,  
  d.v4cust as Customer_Number,
  d.v4scusn as Customer_name, 
  d.v4itd3 as Equipment_ID,
  d.v4snam1 as SalesPerson,
  max(H.v3samzip) as Ship_To_Zip
from [].[HTSTRDP0] d  
left join [].[HTSTRHP0] H 
on D.V4INV=H.V3INVOICE 
  and d.v4ord=h.V3ORD 
  and d.v4cust=h.V3CUS and d.v4indt =h.V3INVDT
where d.V4DIV='3' 
  and left(d.v4item,3) in ('NTS','UTS','FTS') 
  and V4INDT>'20240101'
  and d.v4cust='YANK007' and d.v4itd3='014436-2001STOUGHT            '
group by 
  d.V4ORD , 
  d.v4cust,
  d.v4scusn, 
  d.v4itd3 ,
  d.v4snam1 ,
  H.v3samzip

This is the result I am getting, but I want only one row with the maximum v3samzip.



Order Number
Customer Number
Equipment ID
SalesPerson
Ship To Zip




1425397
YANK007
014436-2001STOUGHT
Briggs, Patrick
01038


1425397
YANK007
014436-2001STOUGHT
Briggs, Patrick
01104


1425397
YANK007
014436-2001STOUGHT
Briggs, Patrick
01373-011




I have tagged this with SQL Server for you, because from the non-standard brackets for the table names, I deduct this is very likely the DBMS you are using. If this is not the case, then please correct the tag.

BTW: I am sorry to see you must work with horrible table and column names. Wouldn't it be great if the table names told us what the tables represent and the columns would be called  customer_number, customer_name, etc. right away instead of v4cust, v4scusn and the like? Having to invoke LEFT on v4item suggests an inappropriate data model, too.

You mention "first match" in your title, but your code is using the MAX() function. Do you want the maximum value or do you really want the first/last/best value based on some other criteria, such as a latest date?  If the latter, you might need to use a SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY subselect - typically wrapped up in a CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY.

Your problem is that in your GROUP BY clause you say, you want one result row per d row and v3samzip. What you want instead is one result row per d row only. So, remove H.v3samzip from the GROUP BY clause.
SELECT 
  d.v4ord   AS order_number,
  d.v4cust  AS customer_number,
  d.v4scusn AS customer_name, 
  d.v4itd3  AS equipment_id,
  d.v4snam1 AS salesperson,
  MAX(h.v3samzip) AS ship_to_zip
FROM [].[HTSTRDP0] d
LEFT JOIN [].[HTSTRHP0] h 
        ON h.v3invoice = d.v4inv 
       AND h.v3ord     = d.v4ord 
       AND h.v3cus     = d.v4cust
       AND h.v3invdt   = d.v4indt
WHERE d.v4div = '3' 
  AND LEFT(d.v4item,3) IN ('NTS', 'UTS', 'FTS') 
  AND d.v4indt > '20240101'
  AND d.v4cust = 'YANK007' 
  AND d.v4itd3 = '014436-2001STOUGHT            '
GROUP BY d.v4ord, d.v4cust, d.v4scusn, d.v4itd3, d.v4snam1
ORDER BY d.v4ord, d.v4cust, d.v4scusn, d.v4itd3, d.v4snam1;

